# cpp how to make main thread wait until other threads are finished in cycle

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to run a cpp code in a cycle in different threads, and want my main thread to wait until all other threads are done. I'm doing like this:

```
MyClass {
    function(Obj1& res, Obj2& input);
}

AnotherClass {
    MyClass class;
    anotherFunction(int size) {
        Obj1* resvec = new Obj1[size];
        Obj2* inputvec = new Obj2[size];

        doSmth1(resvec, inputvec);

        thread* thpool = new thread[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            thpool[i] = thread(MyClass::function, class, ref(resvec[i]), ref(inputvec[i]));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            thpool[i].join();
        }

        doSmth2(resvec);

    }
}
```

But the code returns the wrong answer, however, if I do like this

```
MyClass {
    function(Obj1& res, Obj2& input);
}

AnotherClass {
    MyClass class;
    anotherFunction(int size) {
        Obj1* resvec = new Obj1[size];
        Obj2* inputvec = new Obj2[size];

        doSmth1(resvec, inputvec);

        thread* thpool = new thread[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            thpool[i] = thread(MyClass::function, class, ref(resvec[i]), ref(inputvec[i]));
            thpool[i].join();
        }

        doSmth2(resvec);

    }
}
```

the code returns right answer but does not give an advantage in speed. It seems that I do something wrong in the code, can someone help me? Thanks!
[problem occurs when I call scheme.multModSwitchAndEqualVec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DckTz.png)

[method implemented in Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJLDs.png)

Comment: Sorry, thread I use thread(&MyClass::function, ...)

Comment: `MyClass class;`?  The code as shown won't compile -- please show the *real* code.  If the first code example is giving the wrong answer (you don't state precisely what that means) it sounds as if data is being accessed concurrently from multiple threads so you need to give more information regarding the implementation of `MyClass::function`.

Comment: Just move the `join()` calls out of the loop.

Comment: I posted pictures of two parts of two classes. It either does not finish the program at all, or just gives some answer but different one(it seems that main thread just does not wait for all threads to finish)

Comment: Voting to close because question lacks required information to answer. code #1 probably gives wrong answer due to a race condition; impossible to give more detail because you don't use real code or [MCVE]. code #2 you run thread and wait for it to finish ***one-thread-at-a-time***. If it gives so-called "right answer" it confirms race condition theory of #1; and should be obvious that if threads don't run concurrently - there is ***no benefit*** to using multiple threads.

Comment: PS: If you assumes thread are some sort of magic pill you can throw at code to "make it run faster", you are sorely mistaken and doomed to failure. You need to do some background reading about multi-threaded development first. (And in many cases multiple threads is not necessarily the correct answer.

Comment: I now understand why code#2 is actually just one thread-at-a-time. But why in code#1 the main thread does not wait for all other threads to finish, even if I call join() function for any thread?

Comment: Can race condition occur, if in cycle threads using different objects from the array?

Comment: @AndreyKim: normally not, but because it happens, the first thing to look for is why the thread function is not thread safe.  We can't know without looking at the code of the function which is not included in the question.

Answer (score -1):

when u do join the main thread will wait until the thread will finish, so if u run on loop then main will wait for every thread to finish.
i think what u try to do, is let all the thread detach for but when (i==size-1) let him join.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried to detach all threads untill size-1 and join the last one, but got a different answer

Comment: So you assume that the last started thread will also finish last?  There's no guarantee whatsoever.  The first code in the question is actually the way to go if the thread function is thread safe.

Answer (score -3):

simply increase the sleep time of the main thread by using sleep() function.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I try to make my code to run very fast, less than in one second, is it any ways to avoid sleep() function?

Comment: This must be the worst advice to solve multithreading issue apart from "let's put in a print statement and see whether it fixes things"